# remove text from file

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I want to remove some text from `file1.txt`.

I put the text in the file `tmp` and do:

```
grep -f tmp file.txt
```

But it gives me only the difference.

The question is how to remove the difference from `file.txt`.

Comment: you can make a `sed`  command script with the patterns in `tmp` .

Comment: Either remove "using sed or grep" from your question or remove "awk" from your tags.

Answer (score 10):

Doing `grep -f tmp file.txt` will display all lines containing the word `text` (assume `tmp` just contains the word `text`). If you want to display all the lines that don't contain the word text you need to use the `-v` option to invert the match:

```
$ grep -v 'text' file.txt
```

If you print all the lines in the file but just remove all occurrences of `text` then:

```
$ sed 's/text//g'
```

Comment: the tmp file contain the text that I want to remove from file.txt.
("text" is not a word).

'grep -v -f  tmp file.txt  > file_result.txt'

file_result.txt :  do not contain text which exist in tmp file

Comment: grep works with lines not individual words.

Comment: You saved my day! :D

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove lines from your `file.txt` which contains the line where `text` is seed then you can do something like:

```
sed '/text/d' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -n '/text/!p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is

```
grep -Fvf tmp file.txt
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.   The
          empty   file   contains   zero  patterns,  and
          therefore matches nothing.  (-f  is  specified
          by POSIX.)
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed  strings,
          separated  by  newlines, any of which is to be
          matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert  the  sense of matching, to select non-
          matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
```

So, `-f` tells `grep` to read the list of patterns it will search for from a file. `-F` is needed so `grep` does not interpret these patterns as regular expressions. So, given a string like `foo.bar`, the `.` will be taken as a literal `.` and not as "match any character". Finally, the `-v` inverts the match so `grep` will print only those lines that do not match any of the patterns in `tmp`. For example:

```
$ cat pats 
aa
bb
cc
$ cat file.txt 
This line has aa
This one contains bb
This one contains none of the patterns
This one contains cc
$ grep -Fvf pats file.txt 
This one contains none of the patterns
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is:

```
sed '/text_to_delete/d' filename | sponge filename
```

This will make the change to the source file.

Comment: No need to use sponge, just use '-i':

`sed -i '/text_to_delete/d' filename`